# A question regarding the amount of composite solutions for a equation

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Consider that for some natural value of $x$, we ask, how many values of $k$ are there, such that $x-k$ and $k$ are both composite numbers?

Now, consider that $x=\prod_{i=1}^r p_i$ where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime factor of $x$. And now, consider that by saying $k=cp_l$ where $l\leq r$, we have that $x-k$ is composite and that $k$ is composite. But still, this is only a bit of the values of it. So, if we say that $Q(x)$ is the amount of solutions for this, then, we can say that:
$$Q(x)\approx\sum_{p|x} (\lfloor {x \over p} \rfloor - 1) - \sum_{p_1,p_2|x\;p_1>p_2} \lfloor {x \over p_1p_2}  \rfloor + \cdots$$

So, can someone help me find a better way of writing $Q(x)$?

Comment: so it is somewhat goldbach related ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Q(n) = A073610(n) + n - 3 - 2 \pi(n-2)$ for $n\ge 3$, where [OEIS sequence A073610(n)](https://oeis.org/A073610) gives the number of $k$ such that $k$ and $n-k$ are prime.

Comment: Now added to OEIS as sequence [A331622](https://oeis.org/A331622).